# How to build a pull up bar for a doorway with a door?

Tags: strength, exercise-equipment

I'd like to build a diy pull up bar very similar to [this one](https://cdn.instructables.com/FEE/FFAC/GLL4N9RI/FEEFFACGLL4N9RI.MEDIUM.jpg), but I have a problem: none of the rooms in my house have the necessary frame-without-a-door setup that it requires. Does anyone know of a way that I can build a bar so that it mounts properly on a frame with a door limiting it's ability to brace on one side of the door frame?

Due to my height, this *must* be a hanging bar. I can't use a bar that it screwed or torsioned into the sides of the frame directly, it needs to hang on one side and brace on the other.

Comment: You could try Ross Enamait's diy handholds

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a problem with frames with doors. These bars latch-on to the door frames, and doors don't intervene if you keep them fully open. Just like the below. I have been using of of these and I have no problem doing pull-ups, chinups, or leg raises.[image]

There's another option as well like the one shown in the pic below.

[image]

All of them are available online, for very nominal prices, but as you said you want to build it, the first one would be more applicable to you.

Having said that, always keep the safety factors in mind while using them.

Comment: The last one is nothing for some big guys ;-)